# Altium Design, can't change track width

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, trace

I have hit 3 while tracing, I have hit shift w to open my favorites and it shows me favorites, but for some reason the program will not change the width of traces. It is stuck at 10mil. Anyone know how to fix this issue? Altium 19.1.9 and Altium 20. Tried in both same issue, tried making a new project, same issue. Don't understand what is going on. I just want to change the width of a trace in the interactive router.

Comment: Check your design rules.

Answer (score 1):

Press TAB while routing and it'll open the properties of the trace, then you can change it there.  If your new width choice is outside your design rules it'll give you a pop up about that and then revert back to the previous width.

If the latter is happening, then you need to change your design rules for the PCB.

Comment: And @landon, you can select afterwards the trace and apply tab once or twice and change the whole or partial trace width afterwards